# Using Controller as instead of $scope for ng-map marker directive

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angularjs-google-maps

I'm using [angularjs google maps](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps). I'm trying to figure out how to leverage the viewModel instance (`this`) from a controller instead of using `$scope`.

Lets say I have a simple controller:

```
app.controller("map", ["NgMap", "$scope", Callback])

function Callback(NgMap, $scope){
  this.center = [38.9072, -77.0369]
  $scope.click = function(){
    console.log("clicked!")
  }
}
```

And my html:

```
<div data-ng-controller="map as vm">
  <ng-map center="{{vm.center}}" zoom="10">
    <marker position="[38.9072, -77.0369]" on-click="click()"></div>
  </ng-map>
</div>
```

This works fine, and I can see the marker and click it and see the result in my console. If I want to convert this to leverage the viewModel(`vm`) and instead have:

```
app.controller("map", ["NgMap", "$scope", Callback])

function Callback(NgMap){
  this.center = [38.9072, -77.0369]
  this.click = function(){
    console.log("clicked!")
  }
}
```

I've tried a couple of things all independently, but here they are listed at once:

```
<marker position="[38.9072, -77.0369]" data-ng-click="vm.click()"></div>
<marker position="[38.9072, -77.0369]" data-ng-click="vm.click"></div>
<marker position="[38.9072, -77.0369]" on-click="{{vm.click}}"></div>
<marker position="[38.9072, -77.0369]" on-click="{{vm.click()}}"></div>
```

Some threw errors, others did nothing at all. Any ideas on this? Or does `ng-map`, specifically the `marker` directive, require you to use `$scope`.

Comment: What about  `on-click="vm.click()"`?

Comment: doesn't work either =(

Comment: See [angular-google-maps issue #122 events with controller as syntax](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/issues/122)